# Infragistics Filtered Row Scanning. Goal is to sum of all filtered rows based on column

Tags: infragistics, windows-forms-designer

I have Infragistics UltraGrid which is filtered on different conditions. Now i want to sum of couple of columns from filtered row result. Check following code

```cs
UltraGridColumn column = this.ugResults.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Air45HValue"];
double a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < filtInCnt; i++)
{
    if (ugResults.Rows[i].GetCellValue(column) != DBNull.Value)
    {
        a = a + Convert.ToDouble(ugResults.Rows[i].GetCellValue(column));
    }
}
```

This does not give me a correct answer. I think, calculation is doing on original data source, not on filtered one. How can i do above function on  filtered results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct as I tested it in a small sample application. However, I do not see how you get `filtInCnt` as I would suggest you to use `ugResults.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows()` instead. This method returns all the filtered rows. Then you should for each the collection and perform your calculations. Here is the code:

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Infragistics.Win;
    using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowFiltering = DefaultableBoolean.True;
            this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow;

            this.ultraGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
        }

        private DataTable GetDataTable(int rows = 100)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");

            table.Columns.Add("Integer column", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("DateTime column", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("String column", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["Integer column"] = i;
                row["String column"] = "text";
                row["DateTime column"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }

        private void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UltraGridColumn column = this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Integer column"];
            double a = 0;
        foreach(var row in    this.ultraGrid1.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows())
        {
            var cellValue = row.GetCellValue(column);
            if(cellValue != DBNull.Value)
            {
                a = a + Convert.ToDouble(cellValue);
            }
        }

            MessageBox.Show("Result: " + a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My filtInCnt = ugResults.Rows.FilteredInRowCount.

Comment: I do not know the method name but i think you answered my question. ugResults.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows() is the method which returns only filtered row. Thanks